# How can I Determine a Treshold According to the Precision and Recall?

Tags: python, classifier, f1score, roc

I am gettin these precision and recall values from my classifier and I want to determine a treshold for the test data. How can I determine that treshold? Is these values enough or something else is needed?

Precision: 95.88%
Recall: 97.89%

Comment: I didn't get your question. Can you please elaborate on which threshold exactly you are talking about?

Comment: @DevashishPrasad treshold for roc curve

Comment: ROC curve is constructed on the basis of various thresholds. You can choose the best threshold from an ROC curve which is at the left topmost corner.